# How to add additional fields in FHIR using Extensions?

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I have a payload for **Claim**.
I want to add an additional field **LOB** (*Line of business*) using `extension`, and POST it to FHIR Server, and then search the resource using that field like:
`GET: http://fhir_server/Claim?lob=value`
In the payload I have added the extension block:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Claim",
    "status": "active",
    "extension" : [{
        "url" : "<i entered some random url>",
        "valueString" : "MAPD"
    }],
    "identifier": [{
                    "value": "TEST"
                }],
    "type": {
        "coding": [{
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/claim-type",
            "code": "institutional"
        }]
    },
    "use": "claim",
    "patient": {
        "reference": "f8d8477c-1ef4-4878-abed-51e514bfd91f",
        "display": "John_Smith"
    },
    "billablePeriod": {
        "start": "1957-04-12T21:08:35+05:30",
        "end": "1957-04-12T21:23:35+05:30"
    },
    "created": "1957-04-12T21:23:35+05:30",
    "provider": {
        "reference": "urn:uuid:Organization",
        "display": "PCP79032"
    },
    "priority": {
        "coding": [{
            "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/processpriority",
            "code": "normal"
        }]
    },
    "facility": {
        "reference": "Location",
        "display": "PCP79032"
    },
    "diagnosis": [{
        "sequence": 1,
        "diagnosisReference": {
            "reference": "0316a0c4-0e46-e3fa-a7bf-9e4f3b9c9e92"
        }
    }, {
        "sequence": 2,
        "diagnosisReference": {
            "reference": "932432b0-ac67-0f7a-1382-26c48050c62f"
        }
    }],
    "insurance": [{
        "sequence": 1,
        "focal": true,
        "coverage": {
            "display": "Blue Cross Blue Shield"
        }
    }],
    "item": [{
        "sequence": 1,
        "productOrService": {
            "coding": [{
                "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                "code": "162673000",
                "display": "General examination of patient (procedure)"
            }],
            "text": "General examination of patient (procedure)"
        },
        "encounter": [{
            "reference": "67062d00-2531-3ebd-8558-1de2fd3e5aab"
        }]
    }, {
        "sequence": 2,
        "diagnosisSequence": [1],
        "productOrService": {
            "coding": [{
                "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                "code": "713458007",
                "display": "Lack of access to transportation (finding)"
            }],
            "text": "Lack of access to transportation (finding)"
        }
    }, {
        "sequence": 3,
        "diagnosisSequence": [2],
        "productOrService": {
            "coding": [{
                "system": "http://snomed.info/sct",
                "code": "73595000",
                "display": "Stress (finding)"
            }],
            "text": "Stress (finding)"
        }
    }],
    "total": {
        "value": 786.3299999999999,
        "currency": "USD"
    }
}
```

and created a `SearchParameter` using POST:

```
{
    "resourceType" : "SearchParameter",
    "id": "21761828-b929-416a-8813-d3646cf288f4",
    "name": "lob",
    "status": "active",
    "url" : "https://fhir_server/StructureDefinition/f971fc4998167948838f8a8831ea914c",
    "description": "Returns a Claim with extension.valueString matching the specified one in request.",
    "code" : "lob",
    "base" : [ "Claim" ],
    "type" : "string",
    "expression": "Claim.extension.where(url ='https://fhir_server/StructureDefinition/f971fc4998167948838f8a8831ea914c').value.string"
}
```

but while fetching the result *(GET: https://fhirserver/Claim?lob=MAPD)*, I am getting the full dataset instead of the filtered result.
I also did a `$reindex` on the `/Claim/<resource_id>/$reindex`, but its not listing the field **lob**.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Servers need to be configured to support new search parameters - you can't search by arbitrary elements, only by specific SearchParameters the server supports.  That's true for both searching on extensions as well as core elements.  You'll have to work with the owner of the server to support your desired search capability.  Did you try posting on http://chat.fhir.org to find out if there was a non-extension mechanism to represent "line of business" on a Claim?

Comment: I am using Azure API for FHIR. Also, I dont think the LOB representation would be there, since its our business requirement.